# Does this inequality require to be proved $(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_{j}|)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|) - (\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}^{2}|)\geq 0$?

Tags: inequality, summation

I am working on a proof in which I state that:

$$(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|)(\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_{j}|) - (\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}^{2}|)\geq 0$$*If i=j then $x_{i}=x_{j}$*

Is equal to:

$$(\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|)(\sum_{j\neq i}^{n}|x_{j}|) \geq 0$$

In the whole context, the $x_{i}$ denotes the same sequence.

Should I try to prove that these two inequalities are the same? Or is it "clear" enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already did the proof by your explanation. Maybe I would pack all the stuff you worked out into one line like $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_{j}| - \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|^{2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|\left(|x_i| + \sum_{j\neq i}^{n}|x_{j}|\right) - \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|^{2}\\= \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|^2 + \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j\neq i}|x_ix_{j}| - \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|^{2} = \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j\neq i}|x_ix_{j}| \geqslant0$$

This would be a fine proof.

Comment: Can you explain why you add the $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|^2$?

Comment: @Edward I added nothing. It is an equality. You just use, that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|\sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_{j}| = \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_{i}|^2 + \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j\neq i}|x_ix_{j}|$$ I added an intermediate step to my answer.